# Emitter not adding where players position is

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sknode, skemitternode

I am trying to get a player to collide with a SKNode. Doing so, I want a particle to display an exposition where the SKNode just was(player) and display the effect. When I tried to create this, the emitter is not displaying where the player is. How can I fix this?

```
    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

        let bodyA = contact.bodyA
        let bodyB = contact.bodyB




 if bodyA.categoryBitMask == 1 && bodyB.categoryBitMask == 2 || bodyB.categoryBitMask == 1 && bodyA.categoryBitMask == 2  {
        let player = SKNode(fileNamed: "player")
        let explostion = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "explosion.sks")
        let addExplosion = SKAction.run {
            player?.addChild(explostion!)

        }
        let seq = SKAction.sequence([addExplosion])

        self.addChild(explostion!)
        self.run(seq)

        }

    }
```

Comment: Anyone know?...

Answer (score 0):

Probably one of physics body belongs to player's node? So you just can access it from body. For example let's player's body - is bodyA:

```
  if bodyA.categoryBitMask == 1 && bodyB.categoryBitMask == 2 || bodyB.categoryBitMask == 1 && bodyA.categoryBitMask == 2  {
        let player = bodyA.node
        let explostion = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "explosion.sks")
        player.addChild(explostion!)
        }
    }
```